# How do I use JavaScript/jQuery to populate multiple divs dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologise in advance, I'm not allowed to post images until I have 10 reputation. So, I hope that my description would be enough to get across the idea I have.

So, say I have three columns; a, b, and c. And when there's too much content to be hosted in just a, b, and c, I'd want new off-screen columns to be made, d, e, and f. - This goes on until all the content is used.

So, my current setup has the "hidden-text" div play host to all the content, and then I'd have a JavaScript function, or jQuery function to dynamically populate each of the divs, and create divs where needed along with buttons to then get to the new divs it creates.

The way it determines which to populate is simply grabbing the content and putting it into column a. Column a is full when the content reaches the bottom of the screen. Then it grabs the rest of the content and puts it in b, until b is full and so on until all the content available is used.

I really hope I'm being clear enough, I have no idea if anyone is going to even remotely understand what I'm trying to say... Any help at all is much appreciated!

Here's a code snippet of how the HTML is structured, maybe it'll help someone understand what I mean... Thanks again, everyone!

```
<div id="parent-div">
   <div class="a"></div>
   <div class="b"></div>
   <div class="c"></div>
</div>
<div id="hidden-text">
   This is the content I would like to have displayed across the three divs above.
</div>
```

Here is some JS that I have so far and I'm rather stuck on where to go from here:

```
function Populate(){
//paragraph is equal to all of the content in the hidden-text div
var paragraph = document.getElementById('hidden-text').innerHTML;
var newParagraph = "";

//the variable div would play host to the names of each of the divs in the HTML
var div = "";
//words stores each character of paragraph and passes them into the new paragraph
var words = "";

for (words in paragraph)
{
    newParagraph += paragraph[words];
}
//the column with the name equal to the value of the div variable gets populated by the value of newParagraph
document.getElementByClassName(div).innerHTML = newParagraph;}
```

Comment: Are you talking about pagination?

Comment: How is the content in `hidden-text` related to the content in `a`, `b`, `c`? All I see is a single line, what goes in the DIVs? Are there DIVs inside hidden-div, and you want to copy them to corresponding divs in parent-div? We don't need an image, show what you want the original DOM to look like, and then how the function should modify it dynamically.

Comment: How much is "too much content"? When will it stick with the original a, b, and c divs, and when will it create divs where needed? It's not at all clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar The idea behind the "hidden-text" div is that the JS only has to pull from the one location. A, B, and C are the columns waiting to be populated by the JS. There are no more divs inside of the "hidden-text" div. Think of it like a newspaper, there's no scrolling down, all the content goes to the bottom of the page and then starts one column over at the top again. The idea here is that the JS would populate each of those columns.

Comment: Too much content is when it can't fit on the page anymore.

Comment: How does it determine what goes in `a`, what goes in `b`, and so on? You really do need to post some example data. Not to mention you should try coding it yourself first, then we can help you get it working.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I never specified that, I apologise! The way it determines which to populate is simply grabbing the content and putting it into column a. Column a is full when the content reaches the bottom of the screen. Then it grabs the rest of the content and puts it in b, until b is full and so on until all the content available is used.

Comment: You should put the clarifications in the question, not comments.

Comment: It should be `document.getElementsByClassName(div)[0].innerHTML` since `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of elements, not a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
var divs = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var word_limit = 50;
var paragraph_words = paragraph.split(' ');
for (var i = 0, div_index = 0; i < paragraph_words.length && div_index < divs.length; i++) {
    newParagraph += ' ' + paragraph_words[i];
    if (i > 0 && i % word_limit == 0) {
        document.getElementsByClassName(divs[div_index])[0].innerHTML = newParagraph;
        div_index++;
        newParagraph = '';
    }
}
if (newParagraph) { // If we didn't fill up the last DIV
    document.getElementsByClassName(divs[div_index])[0].innerHTML = newParagraph;
}
```